# xslt check if child nodes exits with a combination of 2 values

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, transformation

I want to know whether if there are any order nodes with criteria id != -1 and status = Active or Done.
See below inputs and outputs for details

**Example 1**

```
<order-request>
 <orders>
    <order>
      <name>John</name>
      <id>1</id>
      <status>Done</id>
    </order>
    <order>
      <name>Smith</name>
      <id>-1</id>
      <status>Pending</id>
    </order>
 </orders>
</order-request>
```

**OUTPUT for above xml should be**

```
<orders-list>
 <order>
      <name>John</name>
      <id>1</id>
      <status>Done</id>
 </order>
</orders-list>
```

**Example 2**

```
<order-request>
 <orders>
    <order>
      <name>John</name>
      <id>-1</id>
      <status>Done</id>
    </order>
    <order>
      <name>Smith</name>
      <id>456</id>
      <status>Pending</id>
    </order>
 </orders>
</order-request>
```

**OUTPUT** 
I should get empty response from xslt( I should not get the `<orders-list>` tag also) because there is no order node matching id != -1 and status is Active or Done

My xslt is failing with the Example 2 input 
For Example 2 I am getting output as `<orders-list> </order-list>`
I should get empty response. I don't want `<order-list>` tag with no child.

```
<xsl:stylesheet>
 <xsl:template match="order-request">
        <xsl:if
            test="(orders/order/id[.!= -1]) and ((orders/order/status[.='Active']) or 
 orders/order/status[.='Done']))">
                    <orders-list>
                        <xsl:apply-templates
                            select="order"></xsl:apply-templates>
                    </orders-list>
            </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="order">
     <xsl:if test="(id != -1) and (status ='Active' or status ='Done')">
        <order>
          <name><xsl:value-of select="name" /></name>
          <id><xsl:value-of select="id" /></id>
          <status><xsl:value-of select="status'" /></status>
        </order>
     </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: The code in your question is meant to allow us to reproduce your problem and find a solution. When you post a sloppy code full of errors like this, you waste the time of people that are trying to help you. Please keep this in mind for next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> For Example 2 I am getting output as `<orders-list> </order-list>`

All I am getting with your code is multiple errors. For example:

```
<status><xsl:value-of select="status'" /></id>
```

is not well-formed XML.

How about something simple:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/order-request">
    <xsl:variable name="eligible-orders" select="orders/order[id=1 and (status ='Active' or status ='Done')]" />
    <xsl:if test="$eligible-orders">
        <orders-list>
            <xsl:copy-of select="$eligible-orders"/>
        </orders-list> 
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```